# Play! Framework Java Project integration with Sencha ExtJS?

Tags: java, extjs, playframework

I am working on a project where I have to integrate Sencha ExtJS with Play! Framework java project.
But could not find any such tutorial or module in Play! documentation.I am curious if this is possible to do? Can someone provide me any tutorial or existing Play 2.x example where Sencha ExtJS is been used as a front end?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant ExtJS APIs are:

- [Ext.data.proxy.Rest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest): A specialization of the AjaxProxy which simply maps the four actions (create, read, update and destroy) to RESTful HTTP verbs (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE).
- [Ext.data.reader.Json](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json): A JSON data reader that reads a response sent from the server in JSON format. It has configuration options to define the relevant properties of the JSON response (e.g. "data", "success" and "message").
- [Ext.data.writer.Json](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json): A JSON data writer that converts a model object to JSON format so that it can be sent to the server. It also has configuration options to specify the message format.

So, in order to have an ExtJS client application interact with a Play Framework server application using REST and JSON, you have to define a resource URI structure and a message format.

The REST proxy example bundled with ExtJS ([see it online](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/restful/restful.html)) shows a way in which these URIs and messages can be defined.

In the Play Framework application, you can define the resource URIs through the routing configuration (see the [HTTP routing documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting)) and handle JSON requests and produce JSON responses using controller actions (see the [Handling and serving JSON requests documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonRequests)).